# actualiza automáticamente el estado de checkbox en db, sin actualizar la página, solo marca y desmarca la casilla | laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, ajax

Si ves
¡La impresión será más fácil de entender!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo cinco casillas de verificación, se usan para agregar y eliminar iconos de una página, por lo que necesito guardar el estado de la casilla de verificación en la base de datos (marcada o no), pero esto debería suceder automáticamente y preferiblemente sin actualizar el página

**más porque tiene que ser automático**: como puede ver, no hay ningún botón para enviar el formulario ni puedo poner un botón allí debido al diseño.

Vi laracasts y varios foros, encontré algunos códigos, pero ninguno se guardó automáticamente, la única forma en que lo veo es forzándolo a enviarlo con ajax o jquery, pero no sé cómo hacerlo y también estoy un poco preocupado por la seguridad, si sucede algo incorrecto, dejaría espacio para una inyección SQL

Este es mi código hasta ahora:

controller

```
public function update($id){

$switch = DB::table('company')->where('representative', auth()->user()->name)->findOrFail();
$checkbox = Pages::select('switch_one')->where('name', auth()->user()->name)->get('active');

if($checkbox == true)
{
    $switch->active = 'false';
    $switch->update($checkbox);
}
else{
    $switch->active = 'true';
    $switch->update($checkbox);
}
if($checkbox == null)
{
    $switch->active = 'true';
    $switch->update($checkbox);
}
else{
    $switch->active = 'false';
    $switch->update($checkbox);
}
}
```

html

```
   <form action="{{ route('xxxx') }}" method="post">
     @csrf
     <ul class="list-group no-b ">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center bg-transparent">
                        <div>
                            <i class="icon icon-wifi purple-text"></i>Wifi
                        </div>
                        <div class="material-switch">
                            <input id="sw1" name="switch_one" value="" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="sw1" class="bg-primary"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces `$switch->update($checkbox)` haces un update del mismo modelo pero nunca se modifica, creo, según tu lógica que en la linea anterior deberias modificar checkbox y no switch

```
$checkbox->active = 'true';
```

Comment: Mira, ayer envié el formulario con la misma función y funcionó, ahora solo necesito enviar el formulario sin actualizar la página, ¿conoces una función de JavaScript para esto?